# Jsoup.connect(url) always throw exception

Tags: android, jsoup

I am developing an android app that using Jsoup to help extract information from web.

My code is like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        String url = "http://www.lcsd.gov.hk/b5/home.php";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        String title = doc.title();
        Log.i("ALAN", "Title="+title);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ALAN", "Exception!", e); //since I don't know how to open the display of stack trace in eclipse...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In addition, I do include the internet permission in manifest already. And also, I tried to change the url to "http://www.google.com/", it worked well and told me the "title=Google".

And the exception is as follows:

```
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575): Exception!
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575): java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: The supported charset name is "BIG5-HKSCS".
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at ava.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:572)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:71)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:408)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:125)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at com.webtest.Webtest.onCreate(Webtest.java:29)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help, very thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the detail and trace of the exception.

Comment: Sorry, can you teach me how to get the trace of the exception?

Comment: Use `Log.i("ALAN", "Exception!", e);` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I just post the trace above.

Answer (score 0):

> 03-14 11:32:07.151: ERROR/ALAN(29575): java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: The unsupported charset name is "BIG5-HKSCS".

This boils down to that your Java platform does not support this charset. I am not an Android user, but I won't be surprised if this has been removed from Android SDK to save precious file/memory space. I'd at least try a software upgrade or inform around on http://android.stackexchange.com.

Note that this is not related to Jsoup. It's just the messenger here.